# How to upload images or icons to use in Slate?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

If Blueprint doesn't have a stock icon that is appropriate for my Slate design, how can I upload an image to Slate myself that will suit my design?

Answer (score 1):

Slate can work with image files uploaded and stored in a folder location; simply drag-and-drop the relevant image(s) into the folder from your desktop.

To reference the image in Slate, use an HTML image and an `<img>` tag. For the image source, click on the file in question to open the preview, then right-click and copy the image link:

[image]

Use this link as the source in your `<img>` or wherever else you want - for example through CSS as a `::before` modifier to insert the image into some existing location.

Note that you *cannot* reference an image in this way within the **Code Sandbox** and instead would need to Base64 encode (or for SVGs include the raw SVG markup) as data that is passed into the Code Sandbox configuration.

Answer (score 0):

u can use via blobster:

put in your css:

```
.navigation-and-action-edit {
content:url(https://foundry.your-domain.com/blobster/api/salt/ri.blobster.main.image.7f12346f-a2ab-43fe-9bb8-b7d5efecb315);
}
```

now you can reuse this item via